# Use Proxy in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, proxy, fedora

The Indian DoT have decided to block `github.com, pastbin.com` and similar services in india. I use zenmate in firefox and chrome to access these site but I can not use commands like `git clone` `npm install`. Fedy and sublime text package control have also been rendered useless.

I tried instructions in https://www.frootvpn.com/ and also followed few other blog post regarding using proxy or vpn in terminal but nothing works. At best, Few techniques enabled wget, curl or yum (thou it is not finding opensuse urls).

Is there any zenmate like application which can provide easy proxy management in Terminal.

OS : Fedora 21
Shell : BASH
Terminal : Gnome-Terminal ( but can also use any other application if it provides solution )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy would do what you want.  As would a VPN, and with a VPN you won't have to set individual programs.

A VPN isn't really called a Proxy.

I'm sure any proper VPN service will do what you want.

It's good to see from your browser when it isn't working, and when it is.

I suggest that to find a VPN service and make sure that it is working, first disable any changing IP  / surf anonymous extension from your web browsers chrome and firefox, so that when you go to www.whatismyip.com you get your real IP.

Then try different VPN services and see if when you go to www.whatismyip.com you get a different IP.

Whatever instructions you follow should involve you from your OS, connecting to the VPN. Details may differ depending on your OS e.g. your linux distro. And once connected you should see the IP of the VPN interface when you do ifconfig from the terminal too.

Once you have achieved that, then try programs from a terminal and i'd expect they should be going via the VPN.

If you don't want to do the VPN route, wget does have a switch to do it via a proxy, see my answer here [How to set http proxy address for wget under windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/526710/how-to-set-http-proxy-address-for-wget-under-windows)   but you would have to find free proxies or hire proxies e.g. free ones here  http://www.mrhinkydink.com/proxies.htm 
 But if you use a VPN service, and test that it works, so your web browser gets a new IP without any particular extension, then you wouldn't need to use a web proxy server with wget.  wget alone - and everything else between you and the internet- would go through the VPN.

Comment: I used frootVPN  https://www.frootvpn.com/ instructions, Still unable to get github working. and also http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn .

Comment: Are there any GUI application to provide VPN like we get in Windows. I am not really a terminal expert. I would like Terminal and Sublime text both to use VPN to provide access to github.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha  My guess is perhaps something went wrong when you tried the instructions..if you found the IP didn't change. I'm not an expert with Linux but Linux distros have GUIs that they call "desktop environments" so for sure you'd be able to do it with a GUI but it depends on your distro(I'd suggest doing it natively not with a 3rd party app).  You really need to rewrite your question with much more info showing your attempts. What you entered into the command line. and/or screenshots of what you did in the GUI. And tag the question with what distro you are using.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha  Also besides improving your question as suggested, try dropping them an email https://www.frootvpn.com/contact/  and post the answer here if nobody else answers it. From their guide it looks like they do it natively for the OS which looks right. So the answer from them would be particularly useful here too, to any user of the distro you are using, Fedora in your case. Also you may ask here https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/questions/

Comment: I have mentioned in the question That I am using Fedora 21 which famously use Gnome 3.14 DE. In windows when I use Hot spot shield, All my apps uses that VPN. But I cant find similar software for linux. I have forwarded mail to Frootvpn, and am waiting for their reply.